# Equation in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I state that I am not studying the resolution of equations in the complex field, but now I should solve the following for other reasons. Since I haven't solved it for a long time, I've forgotten the basic techniques, could anyone give me a hint? The equation is the following:

> $$e^{2\pi ix}=e^{i\theta}$$

I could have been satisfied with Wolfram alpha's result, 
$$x=n-\frac{i\log(e^{i\theta})}{2\pi},\quad n\in\mathbb{Z}$$ but I would be happier if someone reminded me of the process.

Thanks!

Comment: use $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta +i\sin\theta$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If
$$e^a=e^b$$
then by taking logs both sides we must have
$$a=b+2\pi k i$$
where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. This is because
$$e^{2\pi k i }=\cos{(2\pi k)}+i\sin{(2\pi k)}=1$$
so we must have that
$$e^{x+2\pi k i}=e^xe^{2\pi k i}=e^x$$

In your case this gives
$$2\pi i x=i\theta +2\pi k i$$
$$x=\frac{\theta}{2\pi}+k$$
where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.